# i have a leak low sloping porch roof near incline over house

Tags: roofing

I have a leak. I think it’s leaking where the low sloping porch roof meets the small incline to my back windows. The nails popped out and i got a leak. I fixed it temporarily with some wet patch. It is raining alot and gets no sun. It keeps leaking so I pried up some shingles. Now the shingles are just crumbling. I put wet patch over and under them to fix the leak, and it sealed them down. It’s not pretty, but it worked until a hard rain. Recently I went back up to check on it, but the nails are just tearing away shingles when I lift them to inspect.

Should I replace a few shingles with some old extra shingles I have? I do not want leak in house. If I lift up and replace old shingles are there any tricks to cut away old patched area and crumbling shingles without ripping the hot tar paper seal up against house? The incline is heading up to back windows and the ceiling in the first floor back bedroom. Also do I seal the end of the shingles with wet patch, if water pools in that spot?

I have no luck and could really use some thoughts. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack  Exchange. It's hard to understand your question with its run-on sentences and lack of paragraphs. Would you put a bit of effort into making it clearer? Thanks.

Comment: I'd get a roofer there to look it over. May not be what you are hoping but could be the ultimate and long term fix.

Comment: Pictures would help.  What's the pitch of the roof?

Answer (score 0):

With your existing shingles crumbling it may not be wise to try and replace them or you may create a larger leak. I would get a piece of plastic wider than the area that is having issues and wet patch the plastic down under the shingles above the problem area. Making sure the plastic extends beyond the problem area and attach the plastic at the bottom and seal the ends so a gust of air won't lift the plastic. I have used this method many times here in Oregon to stop a leak until the dry season. I know my neighbor left my patch for almost 3 years prior to replacing her roof. I suggest a patch like this since it sounds like your shingles are close to end of life (crumbling).